# best method for hide/show a widget

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

i would like to know if this method is good for hide or show a widget 
maybe a better method ?

thanks in advance

```
ttk::treeview .tree

.tree insert {} end -id "Item 1" -text "Item 1"
.tree insert {} end -id "Item 2" -text "Item 2"
.tree insert {} end -id "Item 3" -text "Item 3"

text .text -bg green

button .b -text "H" -width 10 -command {grid .text -row 0}
button .b1 -text "B" -width 10 -command {grid .text -row 1}

wm geometry . 500x600

grid .tree -row 0 -columnspan 2 -sticky nsew
grid .text -row 1 -columnspan 2 -sticky nsew
grid .b -row 2 -sticky nsw
grid .b1 -row 2 -column 1 -sticky nse

grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1
grid rowconfigure . 0 -weight 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grid remove`.  Change the buttons to:

```
button .b -text "H" -width 10 -command {grid remove .tree}
button .b1 -text "B" -width 10 -command {grid .tree}
```

Of course if you also want the text area to expand into row 0, you
may also want to modify the text area's row.

`grid remove` will remember the configuration settings.

References: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/grid.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think it is depends what you really wants. If you would like to retain the original `grid` configuration in order to use this widget again, you should use `grid remove`. But if you don't intend to use the widget after once hidden, you should use `grid forget`